# @EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ) not working on JBOSS

Tags: spring, aspectj, spring-jdbc, spring-transactions, spring-aspects

I'd like to use ASPECTJ load time weaving with my Spring database transactions (running on JBOSS).  I've wasted an entire day on this but can't get it working correctly.

I've pasted my Java code and also the server's output below.  It's supposed to insert 1 record into the database and then roll back since I'm throwing a `RuntimeException` with `@Transactional` applied.  But when it runs, it always inserts the record and commits the transaction, it never actually rolls back like it's supposed to.

Can you help me figure out what's going wrong?  For refernce, here are links to Spring's documentation:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-spring
- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations

**WEB-INF/jboss-scanning.xml**:

```
<scanning xmlns="urn:jboss:scanning:1.0"/> <!-- this didn't help -->
```

**aop.xml:**

```
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-verbose -showWeaveInfo"/>
</aspectj>
```

**Java Code:**

```
package com.test;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AdviceMode;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableLoadTimeWeaving;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableLoadTimeWeaving.AspectJWeaving;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.JndiDataSourceLookup;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;

public class WebAppInit implements WebApplicationInitializer
{
    public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException
    {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.register(AppConfig.class);
        context.refresh();

        try
        {
            TestDao dao = context.getBean(TestDao.class);
            dao.test();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    @EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving = AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
    @EnableTransactionManagement(mode = AdviceMode.ASPECTJ)
    @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.test")
    public static class AppConfig
    {
        @Bean("vcomDataSource")
        public DataSource vcomDataSource()
        {
            return new JndiDataSourceLookup().getDataSource("java:jboss/com.company.jndi.db");
        }

        @Bean("vcomTxManager")
        DataSourceTransactionManager vcomTxManager(@Qualifier("vcomDataSource") DataSource datasource)
        {
            return new DataSourceTransactionManager(datasource);
        }
    }

    @Repository
    @Transactional
    public static class TestDao
    {
        @Autowired
        private DataSource datasource;

        @Transactional
        public void test()
        {
            String sql = "insert into nest_rhr_customer (rhr_customer_id) values (nest_rhr_customer_id_seq.nextval)";
            JdbcTemplate jdbc = new JdbcTemplate(datasource);
            jdbc.update(sql);

            throw new RuntimeException("TEST ERROR"); //this should roll back the transaction, but it's not working!!!
        }
    }
}
```

**Server Output:**

```
22:43:38,911 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] (main) JBoss Modules version 1.3.0.Final-redhat-2
22:43:39,079 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] (main) JBoss MSC version 1.0.4.GA-redhat-1
22:43:39,137 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015899: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) starting
22:43:43,120 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found SpringDemo.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called SpringDemo.war.dodeploy
22:43:43,120 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) JBAS015003: Found vectrenassets.war in deployment directory. To trigger deployment create a file called vectrenassets.war.dodeploy
22:43:43,139 INFO  [org.xnio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
22:43:43,140 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
22:43:43,143 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] (MSC service thread 1-6) XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.7.GA-redhat-1
22:43:43,149 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBoss Remoting version 3.2.18.GA-redhat-1
22:43:43,174 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
22:43:43,186 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 37) JBAS016300: Activating JacORB Subsystem
22:43:43,187 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 54) JBAS013171: Activating Security Subsystem
22:43:43,191 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS013170: Current PicketBox version=4.0.19.SP2-redhat-1
22:43:43,193 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 58) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
22:43:43,195 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.jgroups] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) JBAS010260: Activating JGroups subsystem.
22:43:43,198 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 49) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
22:43:43,235 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jsf] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS012605: Activated the following JSF Implementations: [main, 1.2]
22:43:43,264 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.logging] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (IronJacamar 1.0.23.Final-redhat-1)
22:43:43,267 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
22:43:43,272 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
22:43:43,305 INFO  [org.jboss.jaxr] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS014000: Started JAXR subsystem, binding JAXR connection factory into JNDI as: java:jboss/jaxr/ConnectionFactory
22:43:43,516 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-/0.0.0.0:8080
22:43:43,518 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-/0.0.0.0:8080
22:43:43,518 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.ajp] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBWEB003046: Starting Coyote AJP/1.3 on ajp-/0.0.0.0:8009
22:43:43,572 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HQ221000: live server is starting with configuration HornetQ Configuration (clustered=true,backup=false,sharedStore=true,journalDirectory=C:\jboss\devstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\standalone\data\messagingjournal,bindingsDirectory=C:\jboss\devstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\standalone\data\messagingbindings,largeMessagesDirectory=C:\jboss\devstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\standalone\data\messaginglargemessages,pagingDirectory=C:\jboss\devstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\standalone\data\messagingpaging)
22:43:43,573 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HQ221006: Waiting to obtain live lock
22:43:43,576 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) MODCLUSTER000001: Initializing mod_cluster ${project.version}
22:43:43,604 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 12.1)
22:43:43,627 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 32) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
22:43:43,635 WARN  [jacorb.codeset] (MSC service thread 1-2) Warning - unknown codeset (Cp1252) - defaulting to ISO-8859-1
22:43:43,651 INFO  [org.jboss.modcluster] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) MODCLUSTER000032: Listening to proxy advertisements on /224.0.1.105:23364
22:43:43,662 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HQ221013: Using NIO Journal
22:43:43,670 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/com.vectren.povect.jndi.db]
22:43:43,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/com.vectren.jndi.db]
22:43:43,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/com.vectren.cevvprod.jndi.db]
22:43:43,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-1) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/com.vectren.cdayprod.jndi.db]
22:43:43,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/com.vectren.cindprod.jndi.db]
22:43:43,671 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS010400: Bound data source [java:jboss/com.vectren.porptvect.jndi.db]
22:43:43,701 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS016330: CORBA ORB Service started
22:43:43,704 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
22:43:43,710 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 36) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
22:43:43,810 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBAS015012: Started FileSystemDeploymentService for directory C:\jboss\devstudio\runtimes\jboss-eap\standalone\deployments
22:43:43,815 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HQ221034: Waiting to obtain live lock
22:43:43,815 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
22:43:43,817 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "vectrenassets.war" (runtime-name: "vectrenassets.war")
22:43:43,817 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015876: Starting deployment of "SpringDemo.war" (runtime-name: "SpringDemo.war")
22:43:43,823 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBWS022052: Starting JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.2.3.Final-redhat-1
22:43:43,824 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-7) JBAS017100: Listening on 0.0.0.0:4447
22:43:43,824 INFO  [org.jboss.as.remoting] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS017100: Listening on 127.0.0.1:9999
22:43:43,843 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jacorb] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS016328: CORBA Naming Service started
22:43:44,274 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HQ221020: Started Netty Acceptor version 3.6.6.Final-redhat-1-fd3c6b7 0.0.0.0:5455 for CORE protocol
22:43:44,281 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HQ221020: Started Netty Acceptor version 3.6.6.Final-redhat-1-fd3c6b7 0.0.0.0:5445 for CORE protocol
22:43:44,357 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HQ221007: Server is now live
22:43:44,357 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) HQ221001: HornetQ Server version 2.3.12.Final (2.3.12, 123) [ef946424-3f84-11e4-a825-5140114d1444] 
22:43:44,378 INFO  [org.hornetq.jms.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) HQ121005: Invalid "host" value "0.0.0.0" detected for "netty" connector. Switching to "DC4PH6Y1". If this new address is incorrect please manually configure the connector to use the proper one.
22:43:44,403 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
22:43:44,404 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBAS011601: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
22:43:44,500 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010406: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
22:43:44,591 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (MSC service thread 1-2) HornetQ resource adaptor started
22:43:44,594 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-2) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
22:43:44,596 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS010401: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
22:43:45,527 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.request.async.StandardServletAsyncWebRequest due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
22:43:45,528 WARN  [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.http.server.ServletServerHttpAsyncRequestControl due to an exception (enable DEBUG log level to see the cause)
22:43:45,583 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBAS018210: Register web context: /SpringDemo
22:43:45,604 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/SpringDemo]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) 1 Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath
22:43:45,623 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed Aug 23 22:43:45 CDT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
22:43:45,667 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Registering annotated classes: [class com.test.WebAppInit$AppConfig]
22:43:45,862 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
22:43:45,936 INFO  [org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Determined server-specific load-time weaver: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.jboss.JBossLoadTimeWeaver
22:43:45,952 INFO  [org.springframework.context.weaving.DefaultContextLoadTimeWeaver] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) Determined server-specific load-time weaver: org.springframework.instrument.classloading.jboss.JBossLoadTimeWeaver
22:43:45,998 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) [ModuleClassLoader@47d6ea60] info AspectJ Weaver Version 1.8.10 built on Monday Dec 12, 2016 at 19:07:48 GMT

22:43:45,999 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) [ModuleClassLoader@47d6ea60] info register classloader org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader@47d6ea60

22:43:45,999 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) [ModuleClassLoader@47d6ea60] info using configuration /C:/jboss/devstudio/runtimes/jboss-eap/standalone/deployments/SpringDemo.war/META-INF/aop.xml

22:43:45,999 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) [ModuleClassLoader@47d6ea60] info using configuration /C:/jboss/devstudio/runtimes/jboss-eap/standalone/deployments/SpringDemo.war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-aspects-4.3.10.RELEASE.jar/META-INF/aop.xml

22:43:46,001 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) [ModuleClassLoader@47d6ea60] info register aspect org.springframework.beans.factory.aspectj.AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect

22:43:46,110 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) [ModuleClassLoader@47d6ea60] info register aspect org.springframework.scheduling.aspectj.AnnotationAsyncExecutionAspect

22:43:46,119 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) [ModuleClassLoader@47d6ea60] info register aspect org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.AnnotationTransactionAspect

22:43:46,124 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) [ModuleClassLoader@47d6ea60] info register aspect org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.JtaAnnotationTransactionAspect

22:43:46,172 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) [ModuleClassLoader@47d6ea60] info deactivating aspect 'org.springframework.transaction.aspectj.JtaAnnotationTransactionAspect' as it requires type 'javax.transaction.Transactional' which cannot be found on the classpath

22:43:46,189 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) [ModuleClassLoader@47d6ea60] info register aspect org.springframework.cache.aspectj.AnnotationCacheAspect

22:43:46,207 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) [ModuleClassLoader@47d6ea60] info register aspect org.springframework.cache.aspectj.JCacheCacheAspect

22:43:46,209 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) [ModuleClassLoader@47d6ea60] info deactivating aspect 'org.springframework.cache.aspectj.JCacheCacheAspect' as it requires type 'org.springframework.cache.jcache.interceptor.JCacheAspectSupport' which cannot be found on the classpath

22:43:46,209 ERROR [stderr] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) [ModuleClassLoader@47d6ea60] info deactivating aspect 'org.springframework.cache.aspectj.JCacheCacheAspect' as it requires type 'javax.cache.annotation.CacheResult' which cannot be found on the classpath

22:43:47,879 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) TEST ERROR

22:43:49,676 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
22:43:49,676 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
22:43:49,678 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 61) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
22:43:49,678 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
22:43:49,679 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
22:43:49,679 INFO  [org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000152: Passivation configured without an eviction policy being selected. Only manually evicted entities will be passivated.
22:43:49,713 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000078: Starting JGroups Channel
22:43:49,757 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) 
22:43:49,757 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) -------------------------------------------------------------------
22:43:49,757 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) GMS: address=dc4ph6y1/web, cluster=web, physical address=0.0.0.0:55200
22:43:49,757 INFO  [stdout] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) -------------------------------------------------------------------

22:43:51,770 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000094: Received new cluster view: [dc4ph6y1/web|0] [dc4ph6y1/web]
22:43:51,793 INFO  [org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000079: Cache local address is dc4ph6y1/web, physical addresses are [0.0.0.0:55200]
22:43:51,796 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Delirium' 5.2.7.Final
22:43:51,802 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering] (MSC service thread 1-8) JBAS010238: Number of cluster members: 1
22:43:51,820 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.TransactionManagerFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000161: Using a batchMode transaction manager
22:43:51,820 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.TransactionManagerFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000161: Using a batchMode transaction manager
22:43:51,920 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
22:43:51,920 INFO  [org.infinispan.jmx.CacheJmxRegistration] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) ISPN000031: MBeans were successfully registered to the platform MBean server.
22:43:51,927 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) JBAS010281: Started default-host/assets cache from web container
22:43:51,927 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 60) JBAS010281: Started repl cache from web container
22:43:51,932 INFO  [org.jboss.web] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) JBAS018210: Register web context: /assets
22:43:52,004 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) JBAS018559: Deployed "vectrenassets.war" (runtime-name : "vectrenassets.war")
22:43:52,004 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 33) JBAS018559: Deployed "SpringDemo.war" (runtime-name : "SpringDemo.war")
22:43:52,017 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015961: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
22:43:52,017 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015951: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
22:43:52,017 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS015874: JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14) started in 13404ms - Started 274 of 414 services (134 services are passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: It is called load-time weaving and it will modify classes when they will be loaded. However your class is already loaded before the load-time weaving is in place so no more change to proces the bytecode.

Comment: but I tried to follow the official documentation from Spring.  What am I missing?

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-aj-ltw-spring

Comment: hmmm, I think I understand it now.  ComponentScan is problematic because it loads the classes immediately.  If I comment out @ComponentScan and manually call context.scan() then it seems to work as expected.  Not sure if that's the best way to accomplish it, will continue researching, but for the time being at least it's working.

Comment: It isn't the component-scan that is problematic (the beans are processed outside of the class loading) however your main class is containing the class you want to proces, making it load eagerly and as such make it not useable for loadtime weaving. When running your app add the `-verbose:class` tag, this will show you which class gets loaded when. You will probably see that your `TestDao` is loaded before the aspectj weaving class.

Comment: i think it's potentially both, i had tried it in the past with the classes separated out too and it still didn't work.  in the end i switch to an xml configuration that enables load time weaving and then injects the @Configuration bean

Comment: Well it depends on when the classes are loaded. If they are imported in classes that are loaded early on, then you probably have an issue. Unless you manually configure the aspect/spring agent on the class path.

Answer (score 0):

Add @EnableLoadTimeWeaving to your configuration